# using brk to get brk_start

Tags: posix, init, sbrk, brk

Manual for int brk(void *end_data_segment); says: "brk()  sets  the end  of  the  data  segment to the value specified by end_data_segment"

On Success it returns 0 else -1.

But how to I get the init value of my break (like sbrk(0))?

best regards,

Comment: What's exactly wrong with `sbrk(0)`? (Both `brk` and `sbrk` are not POSIX, btw)

Answer (score 0):

As the manual states:

> On success, brk() returns zero. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to ENOMEM

So there is no way to get the initial value through a call to `brk`. Instead, as you noticed, you should use `sbrk(0)`:

> sbrk() increments the program's data space by increment bytes.  Calling sbrk()
>          with an increment of 0 can be used to find the current location of the program
>          break.

There is no reason to expect `brk` to also provide this ability when it's already provided by `sbrk(0)`. With that said, it may be more prudent to use use [`mmap`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) in general for your memory allocation needs, due to limitations on certain operating systems for `brk`/`sbrk`.

Comment: Hm... wikipedia says "The current Mac OS X implementation of sbrk is an emulation, and has a maximum allocation of 4 Megabytes.[1] When this limit is reached, -1 is returned and the errno is not set." So should I use sbrk only for init?

Comment: It would help if you described your reasons to use `sbrk` at all. By default, I'd answer that you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @user1735225 I do not know the specifics of the Mac OS X implementation and it is beyond the scope of this specific question, and I suggest you ask another so someone more qualified can answer it. However as Anton mentioned, I would recommend not using `sbrk` at all, prefer `mmap` for your memory allocation needs. Additionally, if the above clarifies your original question, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: it is not about using, it is about implementing :D. I will implementing them as stupid as they are descript... thanks for your help.